# error when upload excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[image]Error when I try to upload Excel file . this only happened in my Edit page (HttpPost).

Hope I can get some solutions and explainations here.

Thanks.

Developing using MVC and C#.

Comment: That depends on where you copied `DataProvider.SelectStoreProcedure` from. Show that code.

Comment: oh, ok sir..got it ;) i need to pass the parameter inside DataProvider.SelectStoreProcedure method, got it..already look into it :) @CodeCaster

Comment: sir, can you help me with this? appreciate your help...  @StephenMuecke